# objective-C - other methods to convert a float to string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I know that you can convert a float into a string using

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", myFloat];
```

My question is what OTHER methods exist in Objective-C that can do that same?

thanks.

Comment: Why? (I'm intrigued.) i.e.: What doesn't the above do that you require?

Comment: I am just researching... having alternatives in the arsenal is always good! :D

Comment: True, it can never hurt to know more. :-)

Comment: And that it looks horribly long compared to Java. You expect there would be a nicer way to do it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

```
NSString *myString = [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:myFloat] stringValue];
```

But there's no problem doing it the way you are, in fact the way you have in your question is better.

Comment: @Digital Robot; I forgot to say that the method you posted in your question is a better method because there's only one autoreleased object (the NSString) this method has 2 autoreleased objects; the NSNumber object and the NSString object. Thank for accepting :)

Comment: Ah, yes, but I have a case right now that it fits perfectly, because I am retrieving NSNumber from core data and using this is perfect. This is why having alternatives to do the same job is good. As I receive NSNumber, converting that to string using my original method would be worst. Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

in a simple way

```
NSString *floatString = @(myFloat).stringValue;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own category method.  Something like

```
@interface NSString (Utilities)

+ (NSString *)stringWithFloat:(CGFloat)float

@end

@implementation NSString (Utilities)

+ (NSString *)stringWithFloat:(CGFloat)float
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", float];
    return string;
}

@end
```

**Edit**

Changed this to a class method and also changed the type from `float` to `CGFloat`.

You can use it as:

```
NSString *myFloat = [NSString stringWithFloat:2.1f];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
float someVal = 22.3422f;
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:someVal];
NSLog(@"%@",[value stringValue]);
```